# Excel get value that corespods to a null

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to access a value in a separate column in excel which corresponds to the first empty cell in my table.

An example is

```
A B C D    
E F G H    
I J K     
L M N O
```

i want to show "**I**" since it corresponds to the first null value in the 4th column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No CSE required:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A1:A4,1/MAX(INDEX((LEN(A1:D4)=0)/ROW(A1:D4),))),"No null values")
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

`{=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$D$4, MIN(IF($A$1:$D$4="", ROW($A$1:$D$4)), 9E+99), 1), NA())}`

You must use Ctrl-Shift-Enter to enter this formula